# Obtaining a list of files to be re-encoded (ideally determining the encoding just once)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
to_convert_files = [FileEnc(filename, getEncoding(filename)) for
                    filename in filenames if getEncoding(filename) != None]
```

The problem here is that `getEncoding` gets called twice for each accepted file name: once in the `if` clause and once in the expression preceding `for`. I know I can avoid this by splitting this into a generator expression that does the `mapping` and a list comprehension that does the `filtering`, but I was wondering if there is a way keeping it condensed in a one-liner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Often, list comprehensions can aid readability. But here cramming all that behaviour into a single line is obfuscation. The Pythonic way is to do the simplest and most readable thing possible.

Here, this probably means writing a generator function that uses a normal `for` loop and skips over elements without an available encoding.

```
def encoded_files(files):
    for file in files:
        encoding = getEncoding(file)
        if encoding is not None:
            yield FileEnc(file, encoding)

to_convert_files = list(encoded_files(filenames))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could process a generator of two-tuples `(filename, encoding)`; this will only call `getEncoding` once for each `filename in filenames`. Also, note that you should test for `None` by identity, not equality (see [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)):

```
to_convert_files = [FileEnc(filename, encoding) for filename, encoding in 
                    ((f, getEncoding(f)) for f in filenames) if encoding is not None]
```